# Passing an SDL surface to a function

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm a bit confused how i pass my SDL_Surface to my function so that i can setup my screen in SDL.

This is my error:

```
 No operator "=" matches these operands
```

My function is this:

```
void SDL_Start(SDL_Surface screen){
Uint32 videoflags = SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_ANYFORMAT;// | SDL_FULLSCREEN;

// Initialize the SDL library 
    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n",
         SDL_GetError());
         exit(500);
    }   
//get player's screen info
const SDL_VideoInfo* myScreen = SDL_GetVideoInfo();


//SDL screen

int reso_x = myScreen->current_w;
int reso_y = myScreen->current_h;
Uint8  video_bpp = 32;

//setup Screen [Error on the line below]
screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(reso_x, reso_y, video_bpp, videoflags|SDL_FULLSCREEN); 
}
```

This function is called in my main function like so :

```
SDL_Surface *screen;
SDL_Start(*screen);
```

Any ideas what the mistake is ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SDL_SetVideoMode` returns a `SDL_Surface*` (pointer type) but you're assigning it to a `SDL_Surface` (non pointer).

EDIT: this is probably what you want then. Return a pointer to the new surface.

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_Start() {
Uint32 videoflags = SDL_SWSURFACE | SDL_DOUBLEBUF | SDL_ANYFORMAT;// | SDL_FULLSCREEN;

// Initialize the SDL library 
    if ( SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0 ) {
         fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s\n",
         SDL_GetError());
         exit(500);
    }   
//get player's screen info
const SDL_VideoInfo* myScreen = SDL_GetVideoInfo();


//SDL screen

int reso_x = myScreen->current_w;
int reso_y = myScreen->current_h;
Uint8  video_bpp = 32;

//setup Screen [Error on the line below]
return SDL_SetVideoMode(reso_x, reso_y, video_bpp, videoflags|SDL_FULLSCREEN); 
}

// ...

SDL_Surface *screen = SDL_Start();
```

Comment: Basically i want to setup the screen and then still use "screen" to blit surfaces too, at the moment its in my main.cpp but i wanted to clean it up into a function.

Comment: @Dave Edited with what seems to be the best solution. What you were attempting required a reference as otherwise it would just modify a local copy. Returning the surface works better though.

Comment: What do you mean by returning the surface? isn't that pretty much your edit is doing now?

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_SetVideoMode` returns a pointer to SDL_Surface.  But `screen` is not a pointer.  You shouldn't be passing SDL_Surface objects around by value anyway, that will mess with their reference counting, and possibly other problems.  You have two options here, as I see it.  Pass an SDL_Surface pointer in by reference:

```
void SDL_Start(SDL_Surface*& screen) {
    ...
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(reso_x, reso_y, video_bpp, videoflags|SDL_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

Or, have the function take no parameters, and return a pointer:

```
SDL_Surface* SDL_Start() {
    ...
    return SDL_SetVideoMode(reso_x, reso_y, video_bpp, videoflags|SDL_FULLSCREEN);
}
```